# POST json data with HttpClient fail

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I try to post some data to web service, this is the object I want to post :

```
public class TSep
{
    public string noKartu { get; set; }
    public string tglSep { get; set; }
    public string tglRujukan { get; set; }
    public string noRujukan { get; set; }
    public string ppkRujukan { get; set; }
    public string ppkPelayanan { get; set; }
    public string jnsPelayanan { get; set; }
    public string catatan { get; set; }
    public string diagAwal { get; set; }
    public string poliTujuan { get; set; }
    public string klsRawat { get; set; }
    public string lakaLantas { get; set; }
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string noMr { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public TSep t_sep { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Request request { get; set; }
}
```

I manage to successfully post the data after convert the object to this format:

```
<request>
    <data>
        <t_sep>
            <noKartu>0000015223116</noKartu>
            <tglSep>2016-06-1209:00:00 </tglSep>
            <tglRujukan>2016 - 06 - 1209:00:00</tglRujukan>
            <noRujukan>0204U0161016Y000155</noRujukan>
            <ppkRujukan>00010002</ppkRujukan>
            <ppkPelayanan>0301R001</ppkPelayanan>
            <jnsPelayanan>2</jnsPelayanan>
            <catatan>test</catatan>
            <diagAwal>A00.1</diagAwal>
            <poliTujuan>INT</poliTujuan>
            <klsRawat>3</klsRawat>
            <lakaLantas>2</lakaLantas>
            <user>RS</user>
            <noMr>RS002</noMr>
        </t_sep>
    </data>
</request>
```

using this method:

```
public string InsertSEP(string parameter)
{
    var func = "SEP/insert";
    var unixTimestamp = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    var signature = GetSignature(consumerId + "&" + unixTimestamp, secretKey);

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-cons-id", consumerId);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-timestamp", unixTimestamp.ToString());
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-signature", signature);

        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameter);
        var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
        var full_url = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", Service_Name, func);
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(full_url, byteContent);

        return response.Result.ToString();
    }
}
```

but when I try to serialize the object to json format like this :

```
{  
   "request":{  
      "data":{  
         "t_sep":{  
            "noKartu":"0000015223116",
            "tglSep":"2016-06-12 09:00:00",
            "tglRujukan":"2016-06-12 09:00:00",
            "noRujukan":"00001",
            "ppkRujukan":"00010002",
            "ppkPelayanan":"0301R001",
            "jnsPelayanan":"2",
            "catatan":"test",
            "diagAwal":"A00.1",
            "poliTujuan":"INT",
            "klsRawat":"3",
            "lakaLantas":"2",
            "user":"RS",
            "noMr":"RS002"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and use method like this :

```
public string InsertSEP(string parameter)
{
    var func = "SEP/insert";
    var unixTimestamp = (int)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
    var signature = GetSignature(consumerId + "&" + unixTimestamp, secretKey);

    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BASE_URL);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-cons-id", consumerId);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-timestamp", unixTimestamp.ToString());
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-signature", signature);

        var stringContent = new StringContent(parameter, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var full_url = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", Service_Name, func);
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync(full_url, stringContent);

        return response.Result.ToString();
    }
}
```

the post fail, what is wrong with the second code, the web server accept json as parameter, I use Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) on my project, I prefer the second method because I do not need to serialize the object myself, and because there will be many different type of object to post.

**EDIT:**
I manage to successfully sending the data by sending json string as data ByteArrayContent like this :

```
// parameter is in json format
var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameter);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
var full_url = string.Format("/{0}/{1}", Service_Name, func);
var response = httpClient.PostAsync(full_url, byteContent);
var responseBody = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

but this still doesn't answer my question, why I'm failed when I send data as `StringContent`

Comment: Don't you need the **data** wrapper? `{ "request": { "data": { "t_step"`

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you mean with data wrapper?

Comment: In the first example you have this `<request>
    <data>
        <t_sep>` in the json example you have this `{ "request": { "t_step"`

Comment: No problem, have you tried to use camelcase on `t_step`? try with something like `tStep`

Comment: no way to do that, the format is determined by the web service which I don't own

Comment: "the post fail" --- what does it mean?

Comment: {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Fri, 04 Nov 2016 01:39:45 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: text/html
}} System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage